# Is there Meteor Any route.ready callback? For easier jQuery event attachment

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

Since meteor creates DOM content dynamically from blaze templates, there is an issue with jquery events attached to dynamic elements.

After every DOM change, some elements may re-appear in application and jquery events need to be re-attached, for example with `$(".element").onclick(...);`

I thought of solution simmilar to `$(document).ready(...);`, but for routes, which may look like:

```
Router.route.ready(function(){
  $(".element").onclick(...);
});
```

This would be an easy solution to use regular jQuery syntax for attached events, and would run after each route has been loaded.

Is there current solution for achieving simmilar functionality at this moment?

Answer (score 0):

The meteoric way of attaching events to DOM elements is to use template events, ex:

```
Template.foo.events({
  'click .element': function(ev){
    ... your code
  }
});
```

This is convenient in terms of scoping, ensuring that you're attaching events to elements that are actually present in a template, and dealing with templates that are rendered multiple times via an `{{#each ...}}` block.

Comment: Yeah, that's the *Meteor* way of attaching events, but it works only for specific template. What I'm trying to achieve is to attach events for many templates at the same time, and by using regular jQuery syntax. Iron router has `Router.onAfterAction` which might be helpful in this case.

Comment: An alternative is to use something like [template-extension](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension) to inherit/share events between templates.

Comment: Event inheritance is an awesome thing to add to the toolbag, thanks David!

Comment: @Dariusz: sorry, it wasn't clear from your original question that you were trying to work around native event mapping.

Comment: @MichelFloyd right, that might have not been clear enough in example code I included.

Comment: @DavidWeldon - this is useful one! ;), There is another solution which is working in my case too: since all the templates which share the same events are in fact subtemplates of bigger one - I attached events the "meteor way" to their parent, and it works for all of them now.